# Angular dialog close button only works in debug

Tags: javascript, angular, debugging, button, dialog

I have a dialog that I open with:

```
(<any>$(this.showAnswersModal.nativeElement)).foundation('open');
```

I have a close button in the dialog that works (closes the dialog) if I am running debug through IntelliJ, but it will not close the dialog if I am not running debug with IntelliJ. Pressing  and/or clicking outside of the dialog closes it whether in debug or not.

Comment: Any clues on how to correct it so it closes from the close button when not in debug.

Comment: Can you please post more code or even better provide an example via Stackblitz etc? This way we can help you better, because we understand better what exactly is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had the event code in the HTML (template) file wrong. I had missed the parenthesis.

I had:

```
(onCloseButtonClicked)="onClose"
```

I should have had:

```
(onCloseButtonClicked)="onClose()"
```

So initially, the event handler never got called, which contained the code to close the dialog, but the dialog still got closed in debug somehow. The code that wasn't getting called in the component initially was:

```
  private onClose() {
    (<any>$(this.showModal.nativeElement)).foundation('close');
  }
```

Somehow running it in IntelliJ debug still closed the dialog when I clicked the close button.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).